# Connecting to a remote database

Tags: objective-c, database, cocoa, sqlite, remote-connection

Is there a framework or class that allows [Cocoa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_%28API%29) and Objective-C to interface with a remote database, be it [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite), [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL), or another (though preferably SQLite)?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the source and compile this yourself but I have read that it is a pain and I think the project may be dead:

[CocoaMySQL-src](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cocoamysql/)

However, connecting to a remote DB directly from an iPhone/iPad App is a very bad idea.  Imagine someone with a jailbroken iPhone and a simple packet sniffer....  It would be incredibly easy for someone to compromise the security of your Database.

The best way to acomplish this is to wrap it in php via a web server on your remote Database server.  You can then run a query on the DB with a simple http POST request and have the page return xml/json/whatever.